# Generated renderscript files cause "Invalid unicode" error

Tags: android, unicode, compiler-errors, renderscript

I'm trying out some samples of Renderscript (currently I'm trying out the [carousel sample](http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip&can=1&q=)).

I keep getting a weird error in the gen folder which just says "Invalid Unicode" , and point at "\u" in each of the generated files, for example (ignore the "...") :

```
 * This file is auto-generated. DO NOT MODIFY!
 * The source Renderscript file: C:\Users\user\Desktop\...
```

So for the "\user" , it says about its "\u" part that it's an invalid unicode. but i'm not the one who generated it.

How can I solve this weird problem?

Speaking of the carousel sample, is there an alternative to this sample, one that might even avoid using Renderscript which does the same, yet even work on old Android APIs ? Maybe one that uses OpenGL instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in our compiler (llvm-rs-cc). I have a fix for this internally in the Android codebase, but it might be a while before it gets released publicly (next AOSP/SDK tools release). I agree with the workaround above (not having a \u in the path) for now. You can also always modify that generated source file after it is created, since it is only in a comment block (and not in the actual running code).

Comment: Are you one of the official Google Android developers? If so, note that the link of the carousel example has a link to a non-deprecated website, but it doesn't contain anything related to renderscript. it simply points to this: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: Also note that Renderscript almost has no tutorials, samples and manuals and the ADT almost doesn't help developing using this language. Not only that, but the graphical part of it became deprecated very soon after it was released. Please try to change the situation as it has some potential.

Comment: We are working hard to make Renderscript Compute more useful to all Android developers. There are samples in the Android SDK and online (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html has links to some blog posts we have made with code). We also are trying to put together some improved documentation.

Comment: Do you know if there is a nice alternative to the carousel ? something that can run on old android versions, perhaps? the only thing i've found is the coverflow sample: code.google.com/p/android-coverflow , but it has a lot of issues (plus it's based on the deprecated gallery view). even for the deprecated gallery there is no alternative that works well.

Comment: Renderscript is only available starting in Honeycomb, so you won't be able to run on Gingerbread or older devices than that. Are you just looking for sample code, or are you looking for the functionality from carousel?

Comment: I know that renderscript is only available from honeycomb. i wanted something like the carousel, but the graphical renderscript is deprecated. i've asked for an alternative to this nice sample because of those 2 reasons. maybe something that uses openGL? or maybe some clever solution that use adapterView ?